# Discord bot that gives a person a role when a message is sent in a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to code a bot that adds a role to a person when they send a message in a specific channel and I cannot seem to get it to work.
Here is the code, please do tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance.

```js
client.on("message", (receivedMessage) => {
    receivedMessage.content = receivedMessage.content.toUpperCase();
    if (receivedMessage.content.includes("PASSWORD") && receivedMessage.channel.id === `channelId`) {
        client.guilds.cache.get("guildId").members.get(receivedMessage.author.id).addRole("roleId");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) has no `members` property. You'll have to access the members' cache.

[`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) has no `addRole` property. You'll have to use [`GuildMemberRoleManager#add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add).

---

```js
client.on("message", (receivedMessage) => {
    receivedMessage.content = receivedMessage.content.toUpperCase();
    if (receivedMessage.content.includes("PASSWORD") && receivedMessage.channel.id === `channelId`) {
        client.guilds.cache.get("guildId").members.cache.get(receivedMessage.author.id).roles.add("roleId");
    }
});
```

Tip: You can shorten your code a bit by just using `message.member`.